# Copy link to clipboard from bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Ive tried using this:

```
javascript:window.open();window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", "LINK");window.close();
```

But would prefer if it would just copied the text to clipboard, and closed.

Thank you :)

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript#answer-30810322) to [this related (but different) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) help? I guess maybe not if there is no DOM...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy text to clipboard from bookmarklet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046972/copy-text-to-clipboard-from-bookmarklet)