# Copy clipboard function working locally but not working server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clipboard

I am using the below script: It is working locally in visual studio. but in server it throws

> "Cannot read property 'write text' of undefined"

```
 function GetCopyText(thislink) {
    var Content = thislink.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].children[0].innerText;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(Content).then(function () {
        // alert('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
    }, function (err) {
        console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: this appears to be JavaScript which runs in the browser, nothing to do with servers really. In which browser(s) are you trying to execute this code? You may find https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard useful

Comment: Pretty sure the protocol must be HTTPS or localhost and/or permissions granted in browser.

Comment: i am using in google chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [navigator.clipboard is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805395/navigator-clipboard-is-undefined) . See also https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi

Comment: If you're using node.js - this package solves the issue: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-copy

Answer (score 66):

Make the protocol https and the browser should run it.

Comment: Yes, clipboard can only be accessed in a secure context.

Comment: I lost 2 hours with this thing! thnx

Answer (score 16):

Clipboard feature is available only in **secure contexts (HTTPS)**, in some or all supporting browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

Thanks Wade

**Suggestions:**
its better to check navigator.clipboard value and proceed only if exists.
This provides good user experience and
In large organizations, since many developers will be running UI in local mode for testing, It saves their debugging time and then figure out navigator.clipboard is not available in local mode without https.