# Safari clipboard error "TypeError: undefined is not an object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

Have an error only in safari browser:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.clipboard.writeText')

I'm passing my current link. What could be the problem?

```
copyLink = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.location.href)
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText(document.location.href)
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        urlIsCopied: true
      });
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
};
```

Comment: The status in Safari for this API unknown probably not supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard

Comment: Always search if API can be used in browser you need to support (check [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard) not sure what one is the API you need). for browsers that don't support the API you need different solution.

Comment: I have this error which popped up in Sentry, on Safari 14, where it's supposed to be supported. I suspect it's disabled in private browsing...

Comment: @vcarel Same here, Sentry, Safari 15.2. Tested and working in private browsing, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please look at the plugin [`copy-to-clipboard`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard). Simply use below code and it's work.

```
copy('Text to Copy!');
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 11):

There are [security limitations on this API](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/) in (Mobile) Safari, one of which is it has to be executed on a site secured with `https`, so will not work on `localhost`, for instance:

> - The API is limited to secure contexts, which means that `navigator.clipboard` is not present for `http://` websites.
> - The request to write to the clipboard must be triggered during a user gesture. A call to `clipboard.write` or `clipboard.writeText` outside the scope of a user gesture (such as `"click"` or `"touch"` event handlers) will result in the immediate rejection of the promise returned by the API call.
>   […]

Comment: Also interesting to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74528564/1066234 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51823007/1066234