# navigator.clipboard.writeText() not working on specific IOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, promise, copy, clipboard

I'm currently using `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`to copy a value from an element to the clipboard however, **its seems to work on all devices apart from the iPhone X and iPhone 6 Plus** in safari.

The browsers are up to date and according to MDN they should work with these versions of safari. The code seems to work on desktop, android and other IOS devices (such as the iPhone 12).

On the iPhone X and 6 Plus it throws a Promise error on both of these devices in the console and also doesn't copy to the clipboard:

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.clipboard.writeText')`

[Full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQQXe.png)

Has anybody experienced anything similar and has seen / come up with a solution? Thanks!

Code snippet:

```
   const coupon = couponSelector.value;
    if (notMissing(coupon) && coupon !== '') {
      navigator.clipboard
        .writeText(coupon)
        .then(() =>
          LOGGER.debug({}, `${LOGGER_PREFIX}: Promise Successful.Copied coupon: ${coupon}`),
        )
        .catch((e) => LOGGER.error({ e }, `${LOGGER_PREFIX}: Promise Failed:`));
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

See [my answer on the post linked in Damian Demasi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72679775/379841), reproduced here for convenience…

There are [security limitations on this API](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/) in (Mobile) Safari, one of which is it has to be executed on a site secured with `https`, so will not work on `localhost`, for instance:

> - The API is limited to secure contexts, which means that `navigator.clipboard` is not present for `http://` websites.
> - The request to write to the clipboard must be triggered during a user gesture. A call to `clipboard.write` or `clipboard.writeText` outside the scope of a user gesture (such as `"click"` or `"touch"` event handlers) will result in the immediate rejection of the promise returned by the API call.
>   […]

Comment: I went through 15 answers to this question until I saw your response (`https`, specifically) - thank you. This answer needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Tried different possible solutions, with no success. I ended up using this package: [copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard).

Usage:

```
import copy from 'copy-to-clipboard';
 
copy('Text');
```

There is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868405/safari-clipboard-error-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object), from where I learned about this package.

Comment: Using yet another package to solve a simple problem seems like a bad idea. You shouldn't need another dependency for something like this.