# Copy to clipboard javascript not working in Mobile devices. What is the issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

The following code is not working on Mobile devices. But works on desktops.
What is the issue here?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  copy();
})

function copy() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("result");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt.innerText);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">copy text</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`navigator.clipboard.writeText\` not copy text to clipboard if it is proceeded by alert() on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69438702/why-does-navigator-clipboard-writetext-not-copy-text-to-clipboard-if-it-is-pro)

Answer (score 2):

Did you see the Browser Compat?

[image: Compatibility for writetext]

If it's not above, try catching the exception:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      copy();
    })

      function copy() {
      var txt = document.getElementById("result");
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt.innerText)
      .then(() => {
        alert("successfully copied");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("something went wrong");
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as i found a clean way to do this.
I found a better jQuery library to do this job.

Just reference this library:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.4.0/clipboard.min.js

Then the texts that need to copy should go for the "data-clipboard-text"

```
 <button id="btnCopyToClipboard" class="btn btn-secondary" data-clipboard-text="@Model.OutPutText">Copy below text</button>
```

Then inside a script tag include this

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(function() {
    new Clipboard('#btnCopyToClipboard');
});
</script>
```

That's it. No compatibility issues. The library will do the job.