# HTML copy to clipboard button is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a button to copy a link ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) to the clipboard, but it's not working. My code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function myFunction() {
      /* Get the text field */
      var copyText = document.getElementById("www.google.com");
    
      /* Select the text field */
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
    
       /* Copy the text inside the text field */
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
    
      /* Alert the copied text */
      alert("Copied link!");
    }
</script>
```

And the button:

```
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Clik to copy the Link</button>
```

Comment: Is the `id` of the link `www.google.com`?

Comment: No, I don't have ID. It's a static link, how i can do it? I just want to make a button to which when pressed, I copy the link www.google.com

Comment: `.getElementById` finds an element with the ID you provided in the DOM. If your element doesn't have such ID then it doesn't make sense and you have to select it in some other way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: No, in all the examples they look for the text to be covered in some elementID. I don't want the user to see the text to be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with async function and await

```
async function copyGoogleLink(){
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText('https://www.google.com')
    .then(() => console.log('Copied'));
}
```

**use this with Event Listener**

Comment: Works well on computer, but not on android

Comment: I get: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')
    at copyLink ((index):1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick `

Comment: `document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', async function(event){
            return await navigator.clipboard.writeText('https://www.google.com!').then(() => console.log('Coppied!'));
        });`        try like this with return

Comment: Get: `(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at copyLink ((index):1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)`

Comment: did you give button an id #button ? like this `<button id='button'>Clik to copy the Link</button>`

Comment: Oh!!! I forgot it. Should remove the onclick='copyGoogleLink()' ??

Comment: remove  the onclick, because onclick is already defined at JS addEventListener

Comment: Now without the onclick, the button doens't do anything, any error but anything copied

Comment: on HTML button: `<button id='button'>Clik to copy the Link</button>`, on Script JS: `document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', async function(event){             return await navigator.clipboard.writeText('https://www.google.com!').then(() => console.log('Coppied!'));         });`. did exactly like this?

Comment: There is a pic: https://paste.pics/3e9e4d5cbc7660c0c054df93518c7878

Comment: Sorry i dont know `const char HTTP_GENERATE_O2BASE_LINK_SCRIPT[] PROGMEM` mean

Comment: It's for arduino, `String page = FPSTR(HTTP_HEADER);

  page.replace("{v}", "Options");

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_IMAGE);

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_SCRIPT);

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_GENERATE_O2BASE_LINK_SCRIPT);

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_STYLE);

  page += _customHeadElement;

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_HEADER_END);

  page += String(F("<h1>"));

  page += _apName;

  page += String(F("</h1>"));

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_PORTAL_OPTIONS);

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_GENERATE_O2BASE_LINK);

  page += FPSTR(HTTP_END);`  and after I run a server with the "page" html code

Comment: on that picture, dont use async function outside document.query selector. or else you use `<button id='button' onClick='copyLink()'>Clik to copy the Link</button>` at a button

Comment: Do I remove async?

Comment: just replace exactly like this `<script>document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', async function(event){             return await navigator.clipboard.writeText('https://www.google.com!').then(() => console.log('Coppied!'));         });</script>`

Comment: Done. Get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at (index):1`

Comment: button still have an id?

Comment: The script is on the header ok?

Comment: `<button id='button'>Generate O₂BASE Link</button>`

Comment: have you try put script under the button?

Comment: I'm going to try it

Comment: if use addEventlistener is good put script after the document

Comment: same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')     at (index):1`

Comment: its maybe because button not detected before script

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/Thyrus/pen/vYZmzXP) i try it works

Comment: True, it works. It's the same as with your first code (it also worked in a simulator). It's weird.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805395/navigator-clipboard-is-undefined. "This requires a secure origin — either HTTPS or localhost". The server where I need the button is a local server 192.168.4.1, so it's not https secure

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  if (navigator.clipboard) {
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }

  const element = document.createElement('span');
  element.textContent = text;
  element.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  range.selectNode(element);
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```